# Error : ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to write Rest Api for download zip file. I am getting the bellow exception. `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.jersey.internal.RuntimeDelegateImpl`.
 I have already defined the bellow dependency in my `pom.xml` file

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>`
```

My rest api code is bellow.

```
@GET
@RequestMapping(value="/zip")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response downloadZip() {
    String FILE_PATH = "C:\\VarunDoc\\Full_Zip.zip";
    File file = new File(FILE_PATH);
    ResponseBuilder response = Response.ok((Object) file);
    response.header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Full_Zip.zip");
    return response.build();
}
```

When ever I hit the URL from postman,I get the above exception. What is causing the error.

Comment: You only compile that class for unit tests?

Comment: @cricket_007 I removed the `<scope>test<scope>` Now I dont get any error. Now When I hit the URL i get the json response. How can i download the file, u can give some idea

Comment: This is the response I get : `{"entity":"C:\\VarunDoc\\Full_Zip.zip","status":200,"metadata":{"Content-Disposition":["attachment; filename=Full_Zip.zip"]},"annotations":null,"entityClass":"java.io.File","genericType":null,"length":-1,"language":null,"location":null,"lastModified":null,"date":null,"cookies":{},"mediaType":null,"closed":false,"allowedMethods":[],"links":[],"statusInfo":"OK","stringHeaders":{"Content-Disposition":["attachment; filename=Full_Zip.zip"]},"entityTag":null,"headers":{"Content-Disposition":["attachment; filename=Full_Zip.zip"]}}`

Comment: Not sure why you get json... Your response should be an octet stream, or a file, not json